# PDF.js reorder pages

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js read the content in page with help of regex. Now I want to reorganize pdf by changing order of pages. Such as move page 15 to 1, move page 7 to 2 etc...

I didn't find such a functionality in PDF.js, is this possible to do?